# Optimisation takes place at which compilation stage

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I was looking for some information regarding when the compiler optimisation takes place i.e either at compile time or run time. I searched web and got a rough idea that optimisations mainly occurs at compile time.
But at what compilation stage the optimisation is done by compiler.
Can anyone please explain the above query.
I am asking this question in context of optimising a C language program using a GCC compiler on Linux.

Comment: Optimization is a compile-time property.  The compiler runs the optimizer phase if you ask it to.  Occasionally, you might do 'whole program optimization'; that's more of a link-time operation — still part of the compilation as a whole, but later than the regular optimization phase.  One question for you: which compiler phases do you recognize (know about)?

Answer (score 0):

For this query, you need to go through the compilation stages to get better idea about optimization. Here is a simple example as a screenshot from my book.

[**Translation of assignment statement**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdonL.jpg)
From the image You will see that code optimization is done after the intermediate code generation phase.